# Streaming Plotly graph offline

Tags: plotly

Can I stream data to an offline Python plotly graph, or otherwise update an existing graph? I've tried just repeatedly calling iplot(), but this creates additional graphs instead of updating my current graph.

Answer (score 2):

From: https://plot.ly/python/file-options/

```
import plotly.plotly as py
from plotly.graph_objs import *

data = Data([
    Scatter(
        x=[1, 2],
        y=[3, 4]
    )
])

plot_url = py.plot(data, filename='my plot')
```

*"If a graph named 'my plot' already exists in your account, then it will be overwritten with this new version and the URL of the graph will persist."*

Just add `go.Stream` to your `data = Data` block to make it a streaming graph.

Comment: as far as the offline question goes, I don't think you can make offline streaming plots, since you need a URL which hosts your stream, and the stream token ID's need to be fetched from plot.ly first

Answer (score 0):

You cannot stream data to an offline Plotly plot.

Comment: Is this still true?

Answer (score 0):

I am able to generate a streaming (or more precisely updating) in offline mode with the help of ipywidgets and a little hacking into iplot function. I did not use the clear_output from IPython.display since it may cause unwanted glitching.

Please refer to class JupyterNotebookPlotlyStream in [this file](https://github.com/hyliu1989/PlotlyOfflineStream/blob/master/plotlyStream.py). At each stream update, you need to provide a plotly Figure object that is ready to plot as the _fig attribute of a JupyterNotebookPlotlyStream instance.

The iplot command (the actual JavaScript command part) will be sent to the browser through a widget. The  of the main display will be updated.

Reference:
https://github.com/jupyter/help/issues/54#issuecomment-236326113